# $.ajax and method post not work correctly

Tags: php, ajax, post, methods

I have a simple code-form like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://myurl/test.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "html",
  data: {
    action: "login"
  },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
});
```

When on PHP server page, I try to print `$_POST["action"]` yet this field is blank. Why does it work fine if I use `$.post(url,data,function)`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and check your console.

Comment: no error...the php script run correctly....the problem is that $test=$_POST["action"]. the $test variable is blank....if i try to use $.post isntead of $.ajax  the $test variable is set correctly.

Comment: What's the content of test.php?

Comment: <?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$test=$_POST["action"];
echo $test;?> 
very simple code

Comment: can you remove path in url and set only the file name where it already placed. in actually in system. like a  url: "htest.php",

Comment: i can't...the resource is on the antoher server....I try to copy Curl syntax and place it in the bash shell and work correctly....the response is right....

Comment: What are you using to see that the value is blank?  The code in your question doesn't include any response handling.

Comment: I' m using ajax response with callback success:function (data) or use the Chrome's console developers to open the php request in a new tab to see the screen writing of my test.php...

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools (the Network tab in particular) to narrow down the problem. Is the request being sent? Does it have the right method? (e.g. do you have an unexpected OPTIONS request?). Is it going to the right URL? Does it have the expected request body? Do you get the response you expect? Does the response have a 200 OK status? If you modify your PHP to output a hard coded string, does that get output correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
      url: "http://myurl/test.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      data: {
        method: "login"
      },
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
});
```

`login` is a php function

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is your solution and how does it solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

You may use `method` instead of `type`.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://myurl/test.php",
  method: "POST", // <-- Use method, not type
  dataType: "html",
  data: {
    action: "login"
  },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
});
```

Comment: They may, but doing so won't help. `type` is not deprecated (and `method` isn't supported in jQuery-old at all).

Answer (score -1):

Problem is solved.....
There is a problem with the callback on success event...and yesterday I focused my attention only on the request php in the developers tool....when I used Curl (with the right request) all work correctly and I forgot to check client code in success callback....
Never use post method with developers console,it's very easy to lose more time :=)